# Use of "i" in function (d, i) in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Can somebody please explain the use of "i". I do understand x, y, width and height. I also understand i is an index, but what exactly it does? If I'm changing my example to i * 2 or i * 10, rectangle just getting wider but remains single, i * 21 makes or i * 42 diving it into multiple rectangles.

//D3 goes under here

```
            var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
                11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];



            var w = 500;
            var h = 100;

           var svg = d3.select("body")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width", w)
               .attr("height", h)

           svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .text(function(d){
                   return d;
               })
               .attr("x", function(d, i){
                   return i * 21;
               })
               .attr("y", 0)
               .attr("width", 20)
               .attr("height", 100)




        </script>
```

Comment: If I'm changing my example to i * 2 or i * 10, rectangle just getting wider but remains single, i * 21 makes or i * 42 diving it into multiple rectangles. I don't get it. What is to do with index and making my rectangle wider, dividing it into multiple rectangle. I'm going through Scott Murray's book, need some help to understand the use of it. The concept here is different to for loop in javascript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument, traditionally named `i`, is the `index` of the element.

For instance:

```js
var foo = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .enter()
  .append("foo")
  .each(function(d, i) {
    console.log("datum " + d + " has the index " + i)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In your case, you said:

> If I'm changing my example to i * 2 or i * 10, rectangle just getting wider but remains single

And the explanation for this is very simple:

If you do `i * 10`, you are setting the y position of the **next** rectangle 10px to the right of the previous one. However, you set the width for **all** of them as 20px.

Look what happens if you set the width for a smaller value, for instance 8px:

```js
var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
  11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
];

var w = 500;
var h = 100;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 10;
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 8)
  .attr("height", 100)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Therefore, since you set the width of all rectangles as 20px, any `i` value less than that will make the rectangles appear as a single one: the next rectangle will be painted over the previous one, and because of that there will be no space between them. Besides that, the fact that there is no difference between the "fill" and "stroke" colours made you think that you had a single rectangle, when in fact you have a bunch of them.

Comment: As always, a nice answer! I admire your patience! Just to add my pedantic sugar: `i` is the index of the selected element, not of the datum, right? You will even get the index if there is not data binding at all.

Comment: @altocumulus Yes, you are right as always, I thought that this way (*"the index of the datum"*) would be easier for OP to understand. I just edited it. There are other simplifications in my answer. For instance, just to add my pedantic sugar as well, `i` is the name of the parameter, not the argument.

Comment: Au contraire, unless you are using the minified version, both, the parameter as well as the argument, are named `i`: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/each.js#L5 ;-)

Comment: Yes, but I meant in the user code: that `i` in the value function is technically a parameter, not an argument, and user can name it anyway she/he wants.